# Finding $\phi(k)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform

If you have $\Psi(x,0) = c(\psi_1 + \psi_2)$ where $\psi_n$ is an Energy eigenfunction for a quantum number $n$.  I'm supposed to find $\phi(k,t)$ at $t$ = 0.  This is for an infinite square well from 0 to a.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this.  I assume since $V(x)=0$ from $0<x<a$ then $\phi(k,t)$ will not evolve in time, thus $\phi(k,t) = \phi(k)$.

$$\phi(k,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{a} \Psi(x,0) e^{-ikx} dx.$$

While, I believe that I'm on the right track the $\phi(k)$ I get is not correct in the sense that when I find $|\phi|^2$ it is still complex, which can't be right.  Can someone guide me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the Shroedinger's equation is:
$$H\Psi(x,t)=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(x,t)$$
so, every wave funtion does evolve in time.

In the case of infinite square well (and also for cases where the potential V is independent of t), we can use separation of variable for the above Shroedinger's equation. Then:
$$\Psi(x,t)=e^{\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}}\Psi(x,0)$$
Now, the wave equation in momentum space is just a Fourier transform of $\Psi(x,t)$ with integral in $x$ variable as you presented.

Moreover, $|\phi|^2$ is always a positive real number for all complex $\phi$. So, if you find $|\phi|^2$ is complex after calculating, please re-check.